# Honda civic 2006 2.2

Tags: honda, civic

At my honda civic 2006 wont start usually becauze the green key rarely seen ,so whats the issue or how to fix it ? Thank you

Comment: When was it last serviced?

Comment: I dont know , but it has 195000 km now ...

Comment: Then get it serviced properly and see how it behaves from there.